# Decimal or Double when storing rounded currency values in an Access database?

Tags: ms-access, double, decimal

I am currently importing a data set that includes currency values into an Access database.  Although I've read that I should be using the decimal data type for currency, can I not use double to cut down on the file size if the values are rounded to the nearest dollar?

As far as I can tell, the issue with using double for currency is due to rounding, but I won't be doing calculations on the data directly.  Any calculations will be done by the application/user.

Similarly, as the data is fixed-length, some of the decimal values are represented by whole numbers.  For example, some fields may contain a value of 12345, but the actual value is 12.345.  This requires that I import the data and then update the values; dividing by 1000 in the example above.

Will using double in this fashion cause rounding errors as well?

Comment: If they're whole numbers, couldn't you make the column an integer?

Comment: This was my initial approach, but some of the values in my tables are too large.  Unfortunately, even the "Long Integer" data type in Access can only accommodate values from -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, divisions can and will introduce rounding errors.

You want to use "currency" for ANY kind of business software. In fact if you don't have a currency data type then you use SCALED integers (you scale the results). You thus store

$123.52

As

1235200

(Assuming 4 decimal places)

The reason of course is "real" numbers in computers are only a representation and are only approximate – they are subject to rounding.

This is SIMPLE code:

```
  Public Sub TestAdd()

     Dim MyNumber      As Single
     Dim i                      As Integer

     For i = 1 To 10
        MyNumber = MyNumber + 1.01
        Debug.Print MyNumber
     Next i
  End Sub

  Here is the actual output of the above:

   1.01
   2.02
   3.03
   4.04
   5.05
   6.06
   7.070001
   8.080001
   9.090001
   10.1
```

Imagine the above – after just 7 SIMPLE and SILLY additions we already getting WRONG answers. And VBA even in Excel will do the SAME. So as noted, we are using 0.01, but it only approximate! (so while we assume this value is  1/100th, it only approximate when using the "real" format in computers.

So computers cannot and do NOT store real numbers to an exact precision. You get rounding errors as a result.

For payroll or anything to do with business applications and money  you have to use scaled integers else your tables and accounting and even reports will NOT add up and you experience rounding errors.

I cannot think of any benefits in terms of storage space unless you storing many millions of rows of data. MUCH worse is if you export this data to some other system, then exporting "real" numbers can introduce all kinds of artifacts and even exponents when exporting - use currency - you be safe in what you see and have.

Comment: So, should I use a scaled integer, or should I use the "Decimal" data type?  Unfortunately, some of the values in my table exceed that which can be stored in even "Long Integer."  Am I expected to rely on "Double" to hold very large scaled integers, or is it exclusively for floating-point?  My understanding was that the purpose of "Decimal" is to house fixed-point numbers to prevent such errors.

Comment: I would used the currency data type if numbers fit. If currency not going to handle your numbers then I yes, using decimal would be my next choice. It not clear how many significant digits, but a double often works ok since there are enough significant digits (15) that any "minor" rounding will not show up. However it seems we gone from about 4 decimal points to now something you saying will not fit in a long integer and that is quite a change. So yes, you best bet then is likely decimal (it is a scaled integer despite the name "decimal"

Comment: Thank you, you are very knowledgeable! So, integer has a value limit, while floating point has a digit limit; 15 for double. Correct? The maximum number of digits after the decimal is 4, but most fields only have 2. Long Int won't work because I have values that exceed -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.  The largest number of sig figs appears to be 10, all to the left of the decimal, i.e. whole numbers.  Since values are greater than what Long Int allows, am I forced to use double regardless?  Also, Access doesn't seems to have a currency type; only a currency format for decimal.